# Multiple choice quiz in Ruby via terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal

Is there any way to code in Ruby so that the terminal presents two options among which the user is required to select using the arrow keys and confirm using Enter?

Pseudo code:

```
p "What is the capital of Scotland? 
user_select = gets.chomp
p "Edinburgh" 
p "Glasgow"
if user_select == "Edinburgh" etc etc
```

I want to know if this can be achieved without the user having to type in their answer. Can the terminal behave like a GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use TTY::Prompt. It will let you use the arrow keys.

Code sample

```
require 'tty-prompt'

prompt = TTY::Prompt.new
greeting = 'What is the capital of Scotland?'
choices = %w(Edinburgh Glasgow)
answer = prompt.select(greeting, choices)
'do something' if answer == choices[0]
```

Result

```
$ ruby quiz.rb

What is the capital of Scotland? (Use arrow keys, press Enter to select)
‣ Edinburgh
  Glasgow
```

Comment: Hi NikK, do I need to gem install anything other than tty-prompt here? It's not letting me use the arrow keys, it just displays as:

What is the capital of Scotland? 
‣ Edinburgh, Glasgow

Comment: Hi James! You don't need to install anything other than tty-prompt. I made a typo in %w notation. I updated the answer, please try again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [Highline](https://github.com/JEG2/highline), though that will not let you use arrow keys:

```
→ ruby test.rb
1. Edinburgh
2. Glasgow
What is the capital of Scotland?
→ 1
Correct!
```

Code (just to get an idea):

```
require 'highline'

cli = HighLine.new

cli.choose do |menu|
  menu.prompt = "What is the capital of Scotland?"
  menu.choice("Edinburgh") { cli.say "Correct!" }
  menu.choice("Glasgow") { cli.say "Wrong!" }
end
```

For more of a GUI, try using something like [MRDialog](https://github.com/muquit/mrdialog/).

Example:

```
require 'mrdialog'

dialog = MRDialog.new
dialog.clear = true
dialog.title = "Quiz"

question = "What is the capital of Scotland?"
answers = [['E', 'Edinburg'], ['G', 'Glasgow']]

height = 0
width = 0
menu_height = 2

selected_item = dialog.menu(question, answers, height, width, menu_height)

puts "Selected item: #{selected_item}"
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this is helpful :)

Comment: In that case you should up vote and/or accept the answer (take your time with accepting it to see what other people say, I'm just trying to explain basic StackOverflow etiquette).

Comment: I did upvote, but my rep isn't high enough for it to be counted I'm afraid